# Use of index [0] in random.choices()

Tags: python, random

What is the purpose of using `[0]` in `random.choices()`? Does `[0]` refer to index of `Lists` or of its sub-lists in the example code below? If I use `[0]`, I get the single random word from the lists, which is the desired result, but if I omit `[0]`, it gives the random sub-list with all of its elements.

Why it is giving the different result for the two cases?

If I try `[1]` instead of `[0]`, The code gives

> index error: index out of range

But if I use `[0]` or `[-1]`, code gives the desired result.

```
import random

Animals = ["Cat", "Dog", "Lion", "Tiger", "Elephant"]
Fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Mango", "Pineapple"]
Vegetables = ["Tomato", "Potato", "Onion", "Brinjal", "Peas"]

Lists = [Animals, Fruits, Vegetables]

word = random.choice(random.choices(Lists)[0])

print(word)
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Obviously doing two different things gives you two different results, why would you expect otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `random.choices` instead of `random.choice`, which returns a list with a single element instead of the element itself. See here:

```
In [3]: random.choices("abc")
Out[3]: ['a']

In [4]: random.choice("abc")
Out[4]: 'b'
```

Calling `[0]` on it returns the element, while `[1]` is out of range because there's only one element. You probably wanted to use `random.choice` (without the s), right?

BTW, [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) is Python 3.6+.

Comment: To clarify for @Gurpreet: `[-1]` is the index for the last element. Since there is only one element, the first element is also the last element.

Comment: Thanks to all especially @Felix for pointing me out the difference between random.choice() and random.choices(), where random.choice() returns a single element and random.choices() returns a list of elements.